# Duplicate flagging

Tags: discussion

It seems that my questions on Stack Overflow are often immediately (I'm talking within thirty seconds here) flagged as duplicates.  I've had three questions which have had that and I've deleted them because there is no way for me to defend myself against those claims.  The problem is, not a single one of the supposed links to the original have been answers to my question at all, but just something on the same general topic. Why is this, and or is there any way for me to revive my questions?

Comment: Yes.  Edit your question to show that it is in fact *not* a duplicate of the linked question and then hopefully people will vote to reopen it.

Comment: @RichardScriven I did that on my recent question and the misplaced duplicate flag was removed within an hour. Good thing normal users can at least try. Last time my question was closed before I could edit, and then it was too late...

Comment: It's **not** too late when the question is closed, though you should have a clear, well-researched, on-topic question from the beginning; the well-reasearched part means you probably noted most near-duplicates, and made sure your question was obviously not a duplicate. Remember, the first edit by the OP of the question, or any re-open vote, will push it into the re-open queue (and that is nearly always empty).

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting so many downvotes, you aren't ranting and you appear to be discussing this constructively..

Comment: @Seth Yeah I know. People who have reputation on this site _love_ the power they have, they downvote and flag like there's no tomorrow. It's unfortunate, because sometimes people just have honest questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that normal users have any way to explicitly unmark a duplicate. Your specific question was marked a duplicate by somebody with a gold badge in one of the tags that your question is marked with - they have a "close-hammer." Their votes on those tags don't require other's votes.

The best option would be to fix up your question through editing to make it *clear* that it isn't a duplicate, and then hopefully people will vote to reopen it.

Otherwise, if you firmly believe that your question isn't a duplicate, you could flag it as "other" and explain to the moderator that your question isn't actually a duplicate. Just make sure to search and search first - there have been millions of questions asked on StackOverflow. It's very possible that your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I do agree that there are millions of questions, and I do always search first, extensively at that.  However, if they really wanted to make this less of an issue, perhaps they should implement a better search engine...

Comment: @PyroAVR that's another very true point. I think they are working on a new search system right now. In the meantime, Google is fairly good at searching StackOverflow.

Comment: yes indeed, I find myself using Google or DuckDuckGo to search other sites very often. I hope SO gets a new engine soon though, that would be a great improvement, and quite a feat, when you consider how difficult it is to search for code when the descriptions are breif...

Comment: **Don't** call for a diamond-moderator ("other"-flag) when the community can take care of it (and much faster). Such flags will, for the most part, be declined. You might want to read about closing and opening question (CV / Reopen queues).

Comment: @Deduplicator do you have any links to look at? I know that I personally don't even look at questions marked "duplicate." Is that really the only way to get a duplicate unmarked? Edit and hope that people with 3000 rep or more will *look*, *cross check the duplicate and the current post*, and then *vote to reopen*?

Comment: Priviliges: 250 Rep for own questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes 3000 for all questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions gold-tag-badge + 3000 for mjölnir http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dupehammer

Comment: @AlexK I'm a moderator on one site, and while the policies on SO may differ from my site, I don't think flagging your post to be reopened is a bad idea or even wrong. Matter of fact, that's been suggested since I've been on the network. I also want to point out that if someone edits a closed question the question automatically gets placed in the reopen queue so it does get automatic eyes; I still don't see a problem with flagging for moderator attention though.